# Simulate native/unmanaged exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception, interop

For the purposes on unit testing I would like to generate a native/unmanaged *CRT* exception in C# so we can test what happens.

I can write a c++ DLL and corrupt the stack etc but I'm wondering if there is a nice way to do this in C#. I thought about calling a Windows DLL incorrectly etc.

Is there any way to reliably generate an exception like this on Windows 10 in C#?

Comment: c/c++ has a few different types of exceptions. Are you talking about _structured exception handling_ (SEH) or _C Language Runtime_ (CRT)? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus

Comment: What do you mean about _"corrupt the stack"_?  If you did that in native code you wouldn't really be able to trust the rest of the process from then on.  If your unit tests are in the same process, you wouldn't be able to trust the outcome since by definition _"corrupting the stack"_ could lead to `corrupted return values` and hence `misleading test results`

Comment: @MickyD I am talking about CRT

Comment: @MickyD I would like to test if it is still possible for us to log an error if such an error occurred. Our application loads native DLL drivers and some of them are quite buggy and we have no control over them, tracking down when a specific vendor is buggy is difficult so at least we could get some form of error logged if this occurred.

Comment: Hmm, well you could easily test this for yourself.  P-invoke a native DLL; throw/corrupt from the c/c++ side and see what happens in .NET.  I do know that even without throwing explicit exceptions native-side,.NET has some safeguards built-in like if you get the p-invoke definition wrong for input or output arguments or if your .NET callback writes incorrectly to `unsafe` memory (been there done that), you will get a .NET Runtime error.  I suspect you will run into one of those.  Try it/or post the code here

Comment: I just wrote a c++ dll that dereferences null in one function and throws an SEH exception in another. Not that big a deal to include it as a reference in the test project. The SEH one is catchable, the access violation is not. The access violation actually crashes visual studio entirely sometimes if the debugger is attached.

Comment: Looks like the only way to log this is to log all calls to the DLL and ensure we flush our logs as well, so if an access exception does occur at least there is a trace of what caused it in the log.

Comment: Yes, pitty.  If you want to have a more stable testing environment you could create a _surrogate_ .NET exe (that your tests invoke) that does nothing but call dodgy DLLs.  That way if the process is corrupted it will only take out the surrogate and not your testing process.  You can monitor when the process exists (gracefully or not) by using `Process`.  If it logs to a file you know things are ok, if not you can assume an error.  You could also use _MS UI Automation_ to auto-click any runtime error dialog boxes OK buttons.  The net result is a stable test environment that doesnt need a human

Comment: We did think about doing something like that. I like the idea. Thanks for your help. If you write an answer I'll mark it as the solution as I think its solved for now.

Comment: Will do, check out my answer below Rolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is a summary of my comments above

---

Yes its possible.  If you want to have a more stable testing environment you could create a surrogate .NET exe (that your tests invoke) that does nothing but call dodgy DLLs. That way if the process is corrupted it will only take out the surrogate and not your testing process.

You can monitor when the process exists (gracefully or not) by using Process. If it logs to a file you know things are ok, if not you can assume an error. You could also use MS UI Automation to auto-click any runtime error dialog boxes OK buttons.

The net result is a stable test environment that doesnt need a human.

```
  Process 1      |  Process 2   
  Unit tests --> |  Surrogate exe  -->  Native DLL
  C#.NET         | .NET                c/c++
```